# Not saved image when creating content on Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, imagefield, drupal-node-hook

this problem:
In the form of adding material has fields with images. Choose a file, click download, the file is loaded, the image is displayed. Others fill in the form and add material.
The material is added, it's fine, but that's only the images are not stored.
But after editing, all the images are stored properly. That is, the problem only by adding material.
I watched the logs of Drupal (admin/reports/dblog), while adding no error pops up.
In what could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Thank you. Sorry for my bad English.

---

Found out that the problem with the cache. Table cache_content. When adding material to the table empty entered information. If you clear the cache (admin / settings / performance). That image will be displayed.

Solved the problem using hook_nodeapi. When updating the material was clearing the cache for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here, but sometimes when editing a node, block, or content type and a picture or piece of code doesn't save, just double check that you are saving the text field as "Full Html".

"Plain text" or "Filtered Html" will strip any `<img>` or `<a>` tags from your markup.

Comment: No, it's not about content, but about a single field image.

I started to understand a bit of it. The database image is added, and the site is considered as if it is not. The $node->field_image_cache are empty (null)

When editing, image are not exists, proposes a new load. But after editin, all right.